# Как выровнять блок по центру?

Tags: css, html

Как выровнять блок `<div class="btns">` по центру?

```css
.btns {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

button:first-child {
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f7600e;
  color: #fff;
}

button:last-child {
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-color: #303338;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <button>HIRE US</button>
  <button>OUR WORKS</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `display: flex` + `align-items` или `justify-content`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /*это для stackoverflow*/
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

button {
  margin: 0 4px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

button:first-child {
  background-color: #f7600e;
}

button:last-child {
  background-color: #303338;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <button>Hire us</button>
  <button>Our works</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть весьма разнообразные способы выравнивания блоков по центру. Самый простой на сегодняшний день - технология FlexBox.

Положите ваш блок `.btns` в какой-нибудь гибкий контейнер, у него свойство `display` должно быть равно `flex`. И с помощью `align-items` и `justify-content` задайте выравнивание.

Вот так:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

```css
.centeral-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: azure;
  height: 200px;
}

.btns {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="centeral-container">
  <div class="btns">
    <p>ЭТО ТИПА КНОПКА</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему

```
.btns {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btns {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}

button:first-child {
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f7600e;
  color: #fff;
}

button:last-child {
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-color: #303338;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns" align="center">
  <button>HIRE US</button>
  <button>OUR WORKS</button>
</div>
```